Upgrade to 24.04 bricked OS: initramfs unpacking failed invalid magic at start of compressed archive
Made the rookie mistake of trusting the upgrade process.
Now upon booting I receive the following error:
initramfs unpacking failed invalid magic at start of compressed archive
Or in recovery mode:

The updater apparently made a btrfs snapshot from before the install. Problem is, even restoring that does not fix this error.
...I looked at the questions here. Every second question I see is a botched upgrade. Welp, maybe by some miracle someone will know the solution, but I'm sensing a full clean install in my future. Why bother with an upgrade if it's so error prone, I wonder...

A full install will be the easiest way out. So many people are having upgrade issues this time. I have been using Ubuntu since 2010, and never saw such huge number of upgrade issues

Boot with another kernel if you have any in grub

@amar Between both snapshots, I have 3 kernels to choose from, all of them receive this error.

Then you have to do what Archisman Panigrahi recommended.

This sounds a lot like the problem I'm having trying to boot from the 24.04 live USB installer.  There's something about my old'ish HP system that's incompatible with the kernel on the live USB.  I was thinking maybe a system upgrade would get around this, but your situation makes me think the upgrade would install the same kernel that won't boot on the USB stick.  I.e., the problems with 24.04's kernel config - not the USB stick setup.  I'm guessing I'm out of luck, and will need to stay on 22.04 until support is dropped.  BTW, the same usb stick worked fine on 2 laptops I had lying around.

I have this same issue with this same board, or very similar. I have a ASUS P8Z68-V GEN3, with bios 3603. I saw this issue when using btrfs for my root partition. This was working fine before with 22.04 and the HWE kernel, which is 6.5 I think.
I was able to resolve this with a reinstall with a ext4 filesystem as my root partition, I got the same error when trying a reinstall on another drive while using btrfs as my root partition.
What's strange is that it's not a grub problem, grub can read the kernel from the btrfs partition just fine, the kernel just can't read it from the partition.
I'm starting to think maybe it is an issue with a buggy UEFI implementation, but I have not had a chance to attempt to boot with a btrfs partition at root using bios instead of UEFI.

Hm... this is not the first indication I see that the hardware might be at fault. 2's a coincidence, 3's a pattern. We might be onto something here. Mint 22 (based on ubuntu 24) also fails in a similar way. That person was also on Sandy Bridge. So unless you're the same person for the mint forums, we have a decent commonality.

I did some more experiments and it appears to be an issue with the on-board SATA controller(s). My motherboard has 2 different on-board SATA controllers. I was able to successfully boot from a BTRFS partition on a HBA, and a cheap SATA PCI-E adapter. I'm not sure why the built-in SATA controllers are suddenly failing with this error, but I'm guessing it's some kernel bug.
